Proving congruence between triangles without using theorems derived from the parallelism concept
I need to solve the following geometrical problem. Given an equilateral triangle ABC, let K be the intersection between the bisector of the angle in C and the side AB. Now let D be the intersection between the perpendicular to the side AB passing in A and the extension of the side BC. Let H be the intersection between the perpendicular to the side AD passing in C and the side AD.

Prove that the triangles ACK and ACH are congruent
Prove that AC is a median of the triangle ABD

Now, I have no problems in proving these points if I am allowed to use the fact that the sum of the angles of a triangle is 180º, or to use theorems related to parallel lines. The problem is that, in the book I'm following, when this exercise is proposed, these theorems have not been introduced yet. I was wondering if there is a way to prove these two points by only using the first two triangles congruence theorems plus basic concepts related to angles (e.g. that supplementary angles of congruent angles are congruent, or that differences between couples of congruent angles are congruent etc.) and not using concepts related to parallelism or the fact the sum of the angles is 180º, but I could not find a solution, I don't know if I'm missing something.

Could you add a diagram instead of forcing us to draw?


If we are allowed to use an auxiliary circle then $AC=CD=CB=R$ is the radius of the circle and  we have:
$\angle CAB=\angle CDH$ because triangle ACD is isosceles.
$\angle ADB=\frac {Arc AB}2$
$\angle ACK=\frac {Arc AB}2$
So $\angle CAB=\angle ACK$
$\angle CAK=\angle HCK =60^o$
And triangles ACK and ACH have common side AC, so they are congruent due to ASA( two equal angles and  the side between).
for the second question C is the mid point of side BD in triangle ABD, so AC is one of its medians.

I was looking for something more elementary, a proof that use only first axioms and basic definitions and congruence theorems, and do not use the concept of parallelism, but I don't even know if it is possible
